# Entity Manager : 3 Tier/Layer Application Question

Tags: c#, architecture, three-tier

I'm trying to create a simple three tier project and I'm on track on implementing the Business Logic layer, right now, this is how my BL looks like

```
//The Entity/BO
public Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }
    public List<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
 }

//The BO Manager
public class CustomerManager
{

     private CustomerDAL _dal = new CustomerDAL();

    private Customer _customer;

    public void Load(int customerID)
    {
        _customer = GetCustomerByID(customerID);
    }


    public Customer GetCustomer()
    {
        return _customer;
    }


    public Customer GetCustomerByID(int customerID)
    {

        return _dal.GetCustomerByID(customerID);
    }


    public Customer GetCustomer()
    {
        return _customer;
    }

    public UserAccount GetUsersAccount()
    {

        return _dal.GetUsersAccount(_customer.customerID);
    }

    public List<Subscription> GetSubscriptions()
    {
         // I load the subscriptions in the contained customer object, is this ok??
        _customer.Subscriptions = _customer.Subscriptions ?? _dal.GetCustomerSubscriptions(_customer.CustomerID);

        return _customer.Subscriptions;
    }
```

As you may notice, my object manager is really just a container of my real object (Customer) , and this is where I put my business logic, kinda way of decoupling the business entity to the business logic, this is how I typically use it

```
        int customerID1 = 1;
        int customerID2 = 2;

        customerManager.Load(1);

        //get customer1 object
        var customer = customerManager.GetCustomer();

        //get customer1 subscriptions
        var customerSubscriptions = customerManager.GetSubscriptions();

        //or this way
        //customerManager.GetSubscriptions();
        //var customerSubscriptions = customer.Subscriptions;


        customerManager.Load(2);

        //get customer2
        var newCustomer = customerManager.GetCustomer();

        //get customer2 subscriptions
        var customerSubscriptions = customerManager.GetSubscriptions();
```

As you can see it only holds 1 object at a time, And if i need to manage List of Customers, I probably have to create another manager like `CustomerListManager`

My question is, Is this the right way of implementing the BL of a three tier/layer design?
Or any suggestion on how would you implement it. Thanks.

Comment: IMHO, you are not decoupling anything with the `CustomerManager` class. You are actually creating an additional maintenance layer ... again, my opinion  ;) . If you really want to decouple, you need to interface with an ICustomer object ... or, as @Chen suggests, look up the repository pattern. And, are you using EF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned before you should have a look at the **Repository** pattern. I would also recommend to check out the **Unit Of Work** pattern as well as **Domain Driven Design** for your application's architecture in general.

You might also have a look into object relational-mapping (**ORM**) frameworks for .NET like [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) or [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate) if that's an option for you.

To give you a head-start here are some great resources to get you on the right road:

**Books**

- [Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268202) by Jimmy Nilsson
- [Domain-Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) by Eric Evans
- [Domain Driven Design Quickly](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly) (Free eBook)

**Online References**

- [Design Patterns for Data Persistence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569757.aspx) by Jeremy Miller
- [Repository is the new Singleton](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) by Ayende Rahien
- [The Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) (MSDN)
- [The Unit Of Work Pattern And Persistence Ignorance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx) by Jeremy Miller

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for the repository pattern, I think it'll answer your needs.

Comment: Do you have any recommended links for research? I am sure the OP will be inundated with tons of repository mumbo-jumbo that will be more confusing.